# How to remove generating button using Laravel domPDF

Tags: laravel, dompdf

Im generating my view as a pdf using domPdf for Laravel
but I get the generating button on my pdf also any solution to remove it please?
When I click my button I get my pdf but also the button included I want to remove the button from my pdf
[This is my view with the generating button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvNXm.png)

Comment: What generating button? Can you elaborate, or show a screenshot?

Comment: @ceejayoz done!

Comment: So, if that button's in your view, you'll either need to a) pass the view a variable like `$dontRenderButton` when you send it off to be rendered (and have the view hide the button if it's present), or b) render a *different* view for the PDF, one that lacks the button.

Comment: @ceejayoz Sorry to be late to answer GMT+1 thanks brother it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Making separate **blade** file for **pdf view** is pretty smart but you can it by send veriable to view in pdf generating functio like this,

```
@if(!isset($anyVariable))
   <button class="btn btn-primary">Generate PDF</button>
@endif
```